# django rest framewok with django oauth toolkit

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set up authentication for my api's. I am new to API's but wish to make more client based web apps. The first problem I am trying to tackle is client side authentication. I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/applications/` (i think thats where I need to go)but it redirects me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/o/applications/` page not found

Heres my code:

Settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
```

urls.py:

```
 url(r'^api/users/$', api.UserList.as_view()),
                       url(r'^api/users/(?P<pk>[0-9+]+)/$', api.UserDetail.as_view()),

                       url(r'^o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
```

api.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

from rest_framework import generics
from oauth2_provider.views.generic import ProtectedResourceView

from serializers import UserSerializer


class APIEndpoint(ProtectedResourceView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Protected with OAuth2!')


class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/issues/121 I needed a login template in my urls